# mysql if statement with string expression

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to use at MySQL Stored Procedure as follows:

```
Set @pr_ans = '($x>22.5 And $x<27.5)';
Set @pr_mine = 2;

SET @v_eval = REPLACE(@pr_ans, '$x', @pr_mine);
SELECT IF(@v_eval, 'right', 'wrong');
```

I always got "right" even I changed value as `@pr_mine = 25;`.

How can I use expression in if statement?

Comment: Can you write it more better !

Comment: Looks like it's not evaluating, you're just getting a truthy response from a string.

Comment: Why do you want to store the expression as a string?  Can't you just give the expression itself, using variables if so desired, as the first argument to `IF()`?

Comment: 'cause i want to use parameter (stored in database table as varchar type).

Comment: @BradChristie: Your answer was good: one *can* use prepared statements in a sproc, and if the prepared statement is `SELECT ... INTO @var` then the result will be available within the sproc too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@pr_ans` isn't actually evaluated, you're just getting a truthy response because the string isn't `NULL`. You probably want something like [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html) instead. How about using the following instead:

```
mysql> SET @pr_ans = 'SELECT (? > 22.5 AND ? < 27.5) AS result';
mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM @pr_ans;

mysql> SET @pr_mine = 2;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @pr_mine, @pr_mine;

+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 0      |
+--------+

mysql> SET @pr_mine = 25;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @pr_mine, @pr_mine;

+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Which would give you `0` or `1` for `false`/`true`.

You could keep use `REPLACE` if you so chose, but you're better off using a prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindly advise... But I can't use dynamic statement in a Stored Procedure...

Comment: Oops, didn't see SPROC part; you're right, can't use `PREPARE`. Well then, you're going to have to create a query that retrieves those values from the database and tests them how you see fit. You just can't test a string and expect a value without `EXECUTE` being involved.